# SlidingUpPanelLayout how make not draggable

Tags: android, custom-controls, slidingpanelayout

i'm develop app & use in my project custom view SlidingUpPanelLayout (https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)
In my case at one of functions moment panel must be don't draggable (in case that content is in full screen mode).
How i can make this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use slidingUpPanelLayout.setTouchEnabled(false); to disable the dragging.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setSlidingEnabled(false) when you don't want the panel to be able to slide. This also prevents dragging.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I try setSlidingEnabled(false), but it's doesn't work.

I found solution. I change drawView layout params as like height

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
 public void changeFullScreenMode(int visible) {
        if (visible == View.VISIBLE) {
            isFullScreen = true;
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            dragViewLayParams = drawView.getLayoutParams();
            dragViewLayParams.height = 0;
            drawView.setLayoutParams(dragViewLayParams);
        } else {
            isFullScreen = false;
            getSupportActionBar().show();
            dragViewLayParams = drawView.getLayoutParams();
            dragViewLayParams.height = absoluteDragViewHeight;
            drawView.setLayoutParams(dragViewLayParams);
        }
    }
```